# Select-object with where-object in expression - $PSitem scope

Tags: powershell

I have 2 arrays:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties UserPrincipalName
$mailboxes = Get-Mailboxes
```

I want to use Select-Object cmdlet to get list where each user from $users array will match mailbox type from $maiboxes array. Match by 'UserPrincipalName' properti. And this is the issue. I assume to use something like this:

```
$users | select Displayname,@{Name='MailboxTypeDetails';Expression={$($mailboxes | where {$_(1).UserPrincipalName -eq $_(2).UserPrincipalName}).RecipientTypeDetails}}
```

As you can see, i have two $PSitems variable in expression: $*(1). and $*.(2) [ (1) and (2) i'v added to your clarity].
$*(1) is represents variable came from "where" pipline, and $*(2) is represent variable came from select statement. Obviously this will not work. Powershell can't difference this two variables
So, the queestion is, how should expression looks?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all this mess,

If you're using the same forest for AD and Exchange, it's already exists in the AD schema, just select the property `msExchRecipientTypeDetails` like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties msExchRecipientTypeDetails | 
Select DisplayName,msExchRecipientTypeDetails
```

and you'll get it all together, also `UserPrincipalName` selected automatically as it's default property.

Comment: Thanks for you responce.
But let's lets say I need some attribute value that stored in $mailboxes array, and can not be retrieved from $users array, and I have to select records from $mailboxes array filtered with values from $users array. How can I perfom this this?